# OpenVPN SELinux Permission Denied

Tags: openvpn, centos6, selinux

I am running CentOS 6.4.

```
# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
```

After some updates, and a reboot, OpenVPN fails to start.

```
# service openvpn start
Starting openvpn:                                          [FAILED]
```

**/var/log/messages** shows the following output on openvpn:

```
Nov 13 14:09:58 host kernel: type=1400 audit(1384344598.334:39761): avc:  denied  { read write } for  pid=5777 comm="openvpn" name="openvpn" dev=dm-0 ino=54527865 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:openvpn_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:openvpn_var_log_t:s0 tclass=dir
Nov 13 14:09:58 host openvpn[5777]: Options error: --status fails with '/var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log': Permission denied
```

So apparently it's an SELinux problem.

I tried updating to **openvpn-2.3.2-2.el6.x86_64** as per [this bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=966373) but no success. How should I debug / fix this?

EDIT: Thanks to both Iain and Jiri Xichtkniha. I changed to location of the log file in */etc/openvpn/server.conf* to read

```
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log
```

which works with current policy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick fix would be to change the log file to be `/var/log/openvpn-status.log` as the openvpn process is running as `openvpn_t` and it has permission within the policy to write to files labelled `var_log_t` (as /var/log should be).

The default context for `/var/log/openvpn` is `openvpn_var_log_t`

```
matchpathcon /var/log/openvpn
/var/log/openvpn        system_u:object_r:openvpn_var_log_t:s0
```

A longer process that requires slightly more management is to allow `openvpn_t` to write to `openvpn_var_log_t` which is the context that /var/log/openvpn gets e.g.

```
echo "host kernel: type=1400 audit(1384344598.334:39761): avc:  denied  { read write } for  pid=5777 comm="openvpn" name="openvpn" dev=dm-0 ino=54527865 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:openvpn_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:openvpn_var_log_t:s0 tclass=dir" | audit2allow -M localOpenVpn
```

which will generate a .pp file that you can install

```
semodule -i localOpenVpn.pp
```

Don't forget to store the localOpenVpn.te and localOpenVpn.pp somewhere safe.

---

For Jiri Xichtkniha

If you look at the generated .te file amongst other things it says

```
#============= openvpn_t ==============  
#!!!! The source type 'openvpn_t' can write to a 'dir' of the following types:
# net_conf_t, pcscd_var_run_t, openvpn_etc_t, openvpn_tmp_t, openvpn_var_run_t, 
  tmp_t, etc_t, var_run_t, var_log_t, krb5_host_rcache_t, tmp_t, cluster_var_lib_t,
  cluster_var_run_t, root_t, cluster_conf_t
```

Note that `openvpn_var_log_t` isn't listed.

Comment: Why so complicated? Yes the issue is that OpenVPN does not log to its subdir by default. He should check ';log' in sample configs.

Comment: it's not complicated.

Comment: "Don't forget to store... somewhere safe." semanage is easy trick.

Comment: @JiriXichtkniha: My reading of the OPs error message is the openvpn process running as openvpn_t cannot write to /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log because the target directory context is openvpn_var_log_t which openvpn_t doesn't have permission to write to. SO you have to allow openvpn_t to access to openvpn_var_log_t surely ?

Comment: I tried the quick fix and changed the location of the log file to /var/log/openvpn-status.log. That fixes the problem, at least for the immeadiate concern.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the SELinux policy to me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use OpenVPN but you have different path to log than prepared OpenVPN policy uses. This would make it work.

```
# semanage fcontext -a -t openvpn_var_log_t '/var/log/openvpn(/.*)?'
# semanage fcontext -l | grep openvpn_var_log_t
/var/log/openvpn(/.*)?                             all files          system_u:object_r:openvpn_var_log_t:s0 
/var/log/openvpn.*                                 all files          system_u:object_r:openvpn_var_log_t:s0
```

The original policy is last line. As you can see it would just accept 'openvpn.*' but this does not recurse to subdir.

Comment: It looks like your commands are just setting the context on /var/log/openvpn to that which is the policy default. look at `matchpathcon /var/log/openvpn`. The `openvpn_t` doesn't have permission to write to `openvpn_var_log_t` which is what the OPs error message is saying?

Comment: I just tried the above commands, but I get the same `avc: denied` message as before.

Comment: man openvpn_selinux

Comment: Tried 'this'? This is good description how to reproduce.